# Can nHibernate Generate Value For Property?

Tags: nhibernate

Id columns can specify a generator.  Perfect.

However, I have a situation in which I need to assign a generated value to a property column if it is null.  Think something along the lines of an invoice table where there's a surrogate primary key column and an Invoice Number column.

`CREATE TABLE dbo.Invoice (InvoiceId  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), InvoiceNumber INT NOT NULL, InvoiceDate DATETIME NOT NULL, remaining columns...)`

This isn't a default value.  The Invoice Number might have certain rules around it's generation.  I have a C# class that handles the actual generation, I just need to find a way to populate the value of the property on the Invoice class.

Ideally I'd be able to specify a generator for a property like I do for an Id in the mapping.  Unfortunately, that doesn't seem possible from what I can determine.  I'm hoping I'm wrong.

I have other, non-nHibernate options I could employ like using a trigger, inserting the generation into the provider.  However, I'd like to keep it a configuration option rather than a coding option.

Does anyone know if a such an ability exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer, but I recently ran into the same problem as you. I backtraced a bit in the NHibernate source and seems like I found a solution.

You can use the NHibernate.Id namespace for Guid generation. There's 2 viable options - letting your client generate the Guid or letting the native DB do it.

These are the classes you need:

- NHibernate.Id.NativeGuidGenerator //DB generation
- NHibernate.Id.GuidGenerator //Client generation

Using the NHibernate.Id.NativeGuidGenerator-class can be accomplished by something like this:

```
public Guid GetNewSessionId()
{
    NHibernate.Id.NativeGuidGenerator guidGen = new NHibernate.Id.NativeGuidGenerator();
    return (Guid)(guidGen.Generate((NHibernate.Engine.ISessionImplementor)anOpenSession, null));
}
```

Good luck with it :)

Answer (score 2):

NHibernate expects that you will define all these rules in your domain classes - for example, in the constructors.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to provide a default-value ?

I would say that this should be something that you should specify at the DB level ...

If you really want that NHibernate takes care of this, I think you should create an Interceptor that would set the value of that property when it is null at flush-time.

Or, you can specify the default value in your entity, by giving the property a default-value in the constructor.

Comment: Not a default value.  A unique value that's generated when a new entity is saved.  I'd forgotten about interceptors.